# Could I use graphx to process local graph separately?

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, graph-algorithm, graph-databases, spark-graphx

After a large graph is partitioned, (I partitioned the graph with strategy EdgePartition2d). I wonder if I could process the small graphs on each machine separately. For example, every machine X owns a small part of the original graph, I want to traverse the local graph or compute local centrality of every vertex in the local graph on every machine in parallel. Is graphx suitable for it? If not, what graph engine should I choose?

Comment: Could you provide some context here. How do you partition the graph? What do you mean by local centrality? On a side note - software recommendations are off topic for SO. I would remove this part if you this question to stay open.

Comment: @zero323 I partitioned the graph with strategy EdgePartition2d. Actually The concept of centrality is not important. What I really want to know is if graphx can allow all machine process their local graph (just use the partition on the machine, treat it as an independent small graph) in parallel separately, and return the answer from all these partitions

Comment: So basically you want to access internal representation? Well, it is technically possible but there is not public API to deal with this if that's your question.

Comment: @zero323 If there is no public API in graphx, do you know any other graph engine which could make it?

Comment: Not really. Since  EdgePartition2d seems to use adjacency matrix then basic Spark tools (`mllib.linalg.distributed`) and some local Graph processing library (for example PySpark + NetworkX) should work just fine.

Comment: @H.A Any updates about the solution?